# Dragging a NSImage from a NSImageView into a web browser, image editor, etc

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Background: when I drag an image from the finder in OSX, I can drop it into many locations: a web browser, or into Photoshop to be opened, for example.

I wish to replicate the same functionality in my OSX app, allowing the user to drag a `NSImage` from a `NSImageView`. Of course, I found Apple's [DragDropImageView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/CocoaDragAndDrop/Listings/CocoaDragAndDrop_DragDropImageView_m.html) example. I also found [this GitHub project](https://github.com/phaibin/DragDropDemo) which extends the functionality further. This works perfectly for allowing me to drop an image onto my desktop or into the finder, in which case it copies the image into a file at the location.

But the system, otherwise, does not seem to recognize it as an image. That is: Photoshop will not accept the drop, nor will browsers, etc. I've noted that `- (NSArray *)namesOfPromisedFilesDroppedAtDestination:(NSURL *)dropDestination` is not called in these cases, which makes me feel like something about the `NSPasteboardType` or `NSDragOperation` is not configured properly.

I can't seem to make much headway with the documentation, here, and most of the examples are more focused with receiving drops into the `NSImageView`.

Thus, in short, I want my `NSImageView` [subclass](https://github.com/phaibin/DragDropDemo) to allow the user to drag the image into Photoshop, etc.

Comment: What exactly is your question? What is your code? What part is it you need help understanding?

Comment: The code is in the links I gave. The question is how to make the image droppable into Photoshop, etc. As I described, I want my NSImageView subclass to be able to be dragged+dropped just like images dragged from the desktop.

Comment: Looks like the code is only sending to a file URL. You need to actually write data to the pasteboard in one of the types accepted by another app.

Comment: @uchuugaka the last function in the code, which sets the pasteboard, calls `[sender setData:[[self image] TIFFRepresentation] forType:NSPasteboardTypeTIFF];`. This seems to do exactly what you're saying, unless I misunderstand...